# For this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$L\frac{d^2q}{dt^2}+R\frac{dq}{dt}+\frac{q}{C}=V$
given that R=0, L=0.4,  ,C=0.1, V=$110\sin \omega t$  and  $q(0)=1$, $q'(0)=0$

1.Write down the differential equation satisfied by q(t) in this circuit.
2.Determine the value(s) of $\omega$ so that resonance occurs in the circuit and when resonance does not occur.

My approach:

differential equation is $q''+25q=275\sin \omega t$
so $q_H(x)=Acos 5t+Bsin 5t$
applying initial conditions i got $q_H(x)=\cos5t$
resonance occurs when $275\sin \omega t$ is a a part of the general solution of homogenouse

so the resonance will occur when $\omega$=5?

Thanks

Comment: Provided $\omega\ne5$, you have $q(t)=\frac{275}{25-\omega^2}\sin\omega t+\cos 5t+B\sin 5t$. so $q'(0)=\frac{275\omega}{25-\omega^2}+5B=0$. That does not give $B=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
L\frac{d^2q}{dt^2}+\frac{q}{C}=V_0\sin{\omega t}
$$
where $L=0.4$, $C=0.1$ and $V_0=110$.
Applying Laplace transform we have
$$
L\left[s^2Q(s)-sq(0)-q'(0)\right]+\frac{Q(s)}{C}=V_0\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$
and with $q(0)=1$ and $q'(0)=0$ we find
$$
(s^2+\omega_0^2)Q(s)-s=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$
where $\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}=5$ and then
\begin{align}
Q(s)&=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{\omega}{(s^2+\omega^2)(s^2+\omega_0^2)}+\frac{s}{s^2+\omega_0^2}\\
&=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{\omega}{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}\left[\frac{1}{s^2+\omega_0^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+\omega^2}\right]+\frac{s}{s^2+\omega_0^2}\\
&=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{1}{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\frac{\omega_0}{s^2+\omega_0^2}-\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\right]+\frac{s}{s^2+\omega_0^2}
\end{align}
So the inverse Laplace transform gives
\begin{align}
q(t)=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{1}{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0 t)-\sin(\omega t)\right]+\cos(\omega_0 t)
\end{align}
and for $\omega\to\omega_0$ we find
\begin{align}
q_0(t)=\lim_{\omega\to\omega_0}q(t)=\frac{V_0}{L}\frac{1}{2\omega_0^2}\left[\sin(\omega_0 t)-(\omega_0 t)\cos(\omega_0 t)\right]+\cos(\omega_0 t)
\end{align}